# How to open a lock if key broke into the lock?

Tags: locks, keys

If you are in hurry an the key broke into the lock of a door or closet an key maker is not available, then how to deal with such an emergency situation saving the door?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This YouTube video shows many ways to get through a door without picking the lock or breaking the door.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnmcRTnTNC8

Answer (score 3):

If a short bit of the key is still sticking out of the lock, you may be able to grab it tightly with a pair of pliers and slowly pull the half-key out. That will allow other keys to be inserted into the lock.

[image]

If that's the only key you had, then you may be able to use it (temporarily!) by holding it with the pliers. Soon you **will** need to get a new key cut to match it. A key-maker may be able to do that from the half-key that you still have.

Answer (score 0):

If a tiny bit of the key is sticking out, a pair of nail clippers might work. They make it easier to apply force than tweezers do.

[image]
[image]

You will likely bend or dull the nail clippers, but it's a good "home remedy" if you need to get the key out in a hurry—maybe you have a spare, or you can use a key duplication method like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lo6AN4drp08):

[image]